# Sum of two squares mod p using primitive root

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, modular-arithmetic, finite-fields, pigeonhole-principle

My question is as follows (Problem 5.2 in Aluffi, *Algebra: Chapter 0*):

**Question.** For any finite field $F := \mathbb{F}_{p^d}$, show that any element $k$ can be written as a sum of two squares, i.e. there exists $x,y\in F$ such that $k = x^2 + y^2$.

I am wondering *if there is a solution using primitive elements of the field $F$*, as suggested by Aluffi in the hint.

The same question has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/891861/sum-of-two-squares-modulo-p), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1266433/squares-in-a-finite-field?noredirect=1&lq=1), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1163696/does-this-equation-in-mathbbz-p-always-have-a-solution?noredirect=1&lq=1). However, all of the given answers are combinatorial (using Pigeonhole Principle), and they are not what I am looking for.

Comment: Some related material [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1690454/11619). Rehashing the ideas. A) It suffices to show that some non-square $n\in F$ is a sum of two squares, because every non-square has the form $(g^a)^2n$, where $a$ is a natural number and $g$ is a primitive element. B) Mikhail Ivanov's argument settles the case of prime fields as follows: Let $n$ be the smallest quadratic non-residue modulo $p$. Then $n-1$ is a quadratic residue and $n-1=x^2$. So $n=x^2+1$ is a sum of two squares and we are done by part A.

Comment: (cont'd) Alas, I don't see a way to tweak the argument in B to work for non-prime fields also. I suspect something along these lines works, but...

Comment: Anyway, there are $(p^d+1)/2$ squares in $F$, so they cannot form an additive subgroup (Lagrange). Therefore some sum of two squares is a non-square, and the argument A) kicks in. Leaving this as a comment for now, because I'm not sure that this is what you are looking for? It does not really use a primitive element. After all, we only the fact the ratio of two non-squares in $F$ is a square for the argument A to work.

Comment: Last but not least: $\huge{+1}$ for having searched the site before asking. If everybody did that, the site would be much better off!